# Is there anyway in flex to poll the keyboard?

Tags: apache-flex, keyboard, air

I'd like to tell if a certain key is being held down around the startup of my AIR (desktop) application, and I'd like to tell if a specific key (<kbd>ALT</kbd> in this case) is being held down. Unfortunately, flex seems to be so event based that there is no way poll the keyboard directly. Can anyone verify this?

I know that it's possible to take the keyboard events and keep track manually. However, this won't work if the user presses the key right before startup, so it isn't a solution for my specific problem.

Comment: Could you detect this using Javascript and then pass it to your Flex application via the ExternalInterface?

Comment: The flash.ui.Keyboard class has static Booleans for Num Lock and Caps Lock that you'd be able to poll. I didn't see anything for Alt though.

Comment: @sean, sorry, I thought AIR would clarify that it was a desktop-based application. I've edited the post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my app I track ctrl pressed via listening stage MOUSE_MOVE, MOUSE_DOWN and KEY_DOWN. MouseEvent has ctrlKey and altKey properties. I store state in some static variable . When I longer need this I unsubscribe from these events.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Now, it's safe it assume the user will move the mouse eventually, but this does depend on user action, right? Flex doesn't just regularly fire off mouse events I imagine. I ask because I can imagine a user holding down alt, waiting for the result to happen, nothing happens, they move the mouse and then it fires.

Comment: Yeah, it's not cover 99% cases. But still enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you listen for key up, then you should hear this if the key was down.  So you won't actually know right *at* startup, but when they release the key.  You can unsubscribe from that event at some point that you determine is "after startup."

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. Unfortunately, in my circumstance this wouldn't be of any use. The goal is to present the user with a dialogue box to choose which database to load, so in most cases they will think it isn't working or will probably lift the alt key 15 seconds in.

Comment: What is the down side of not choosing the database for 15 seconds?  It seems likely they will lift the Alt key before they move the mouse (who holds down the alt key while moving the mouse?)

Comment: It's a dashboarding tool, so the idea is to give the advanced users the ability to load an alternate dashboard on startup. So I guess the issue in either case is a weird user interaction model. You end up with this sort of secondary user action firing off the event which can be quite confusing. You do have a point about the mouse usage. It seems like the best solution so far is to check for both mouse and keyup.